# error in python plot: unwanted line in the plot

Tags: python, plot

I am very new to python. I tried to make a plot by loading a .txt file that contains two arrays of numbers. The plot looks fine, but there is an additional line which I am unable to get rid of. I have attached my code here. Please help!
Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numpy import genfromtxt

data= genfromtxt ('PVC_Cs137.txt')
plt.plot(data)
plt.xlim(0,2500)
plt.ylim(0,30000)
plt.xlabel("Channel number")
plt.ylabel("Counts")
plt.show()
```

[Link to the data](http://dropbox.com/s/hrqjr2jgfsjs55x/PVC_Cs137.txt?dl=0)

Comment: What is your data?

Comment: Sorry. Here is the link to my file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/hrqjr2jgfsjs55x/PVC_Cs137.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this should work for you:

```
data= genfromtxt ('PVC_Cs137.txt')
plt.plot(data[:,0], data[:,1])
plt.xlim(0,2500)
plt.ylim(0,30000)
plt.xlabel("Channel number")
plt.ylabel("Counts")
plt.show()
```

[image]

This explicitly tells matplotlib that you want to plot the first index of your data against the second index

Comment: Glad to hear it!